# Replying to a specific Facebook comment using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to *post* a reply to a specific comment using Graph API Explorer. How can I do that? I tried several suggestions including
`POST /{parent_comment_id}/comments?message={message}`, but couldn't just post a reply to a specific comment. Please help.

Please have a look at the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the {} from your url. It should be `graph.facebook.com/v2.12/5568669414690512/comments?message=Hello`

Answer (score 1):

Just make a POST request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/{{comment_id}}/comments?access_token={{access_token}}
```

add the body of the request as a JSON

```
{
    "message" : "reply"
}
```